# Why does flutter component keeps loading when I use it with Provider and Stream Builder?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am using Provider package to fetch all data from Firebase once and pass it to the child widgets. Before I started using Provider, I used Future Builder to fetch the data and show with StreamBuilder. It was working well. But it increases the Firestore reads.
So I shifted to Provider package, Provider is working but when data arrives to StreamBuilder, the UI keeps loading and stopping (look like blinking). When I checked this in Debugging mode, I saw StreamBuilder UI is rendering back again and again. What could be the case? Here is the code of this. The output of the error is here -> [Error output of UI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxzFFYvc3exjz7iLfZX4S80IJ9z_ybER/view?usp=sharing)

> HomeProvider.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class HomeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  var userInfo;
  Map<String, dynamic> get getcurrentUserInfo => userInfo;

  String uid;
  String get userID => uid;

  CollectionReference meetings;
  CollectionReference get getMeetings => meetings;

  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future getuserinfo() async {
    uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userProfiles')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
    userInfo = user.data();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future fetchMeetings() async {
    meetings = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meetings');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I called the function to fetch data in Provider on Home Widget.

> Home.dart

```
Future fetchFromProvider() async {
    HomeProvider homeProvider = Provider.of<HomeProvider>(context);
    await homeProvider.getuserinfo();
    await homeProvider.fetchMeetings();
   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fetchFromProvider();
....
}
```

This is where Error is happening...

> MeetingList.dart

```
class MeetingList extends StatelessWidget {
  var userInfo;
  CollectionReference meetings_Provider;
  Map<String, dynamic> currentUser;
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    HomeProvider homeProvider = Provider.of<HomeProvider>(context);
    meetings_Provider = homeProvider.getMeetings;
    currentUser = homeProvider.getcurrentUserInfo;
    print(currentUser.values);
   
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: meetings_Provider.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return LoadingIndicator();
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            //print(document.data());
            String meetingRole = document.data()['role'];
            var userRole = currentUser['role'];
            print(userRole);
            if (meetingRole == 'all' || meetingRole == userRole) {
              return Meeting_Card(
                meeting: document.data(),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
homeprovider = Provider.of<HomeProvider>(context,listen:false);
```

Comment: I am doing. Stackoverflow said I can accpet answer within 2 minutes only. Sorry bro !